# Best way to paint on a texture map?

Tags: 3d, texture, maps

Let's say I've got a UV map with defined edges of the certain elements of an object and white lines inside those edges.

What is the best way to paint upon that? It seems a little bit unnatural (as I'm only starting) to create a texture upon those. I've been trying out 3DCoat which allows you to edit the object in the external editor in the plane you want (for example, from right/left side, I think Blender also allows that). But the end result is not the same as if you were painting on the texture map itself. The difference is that when you paint in such a way, the painting is applied in a different way (not that precise I would say). It's easier though. What is a common way and how to get used to it and understand how you should properly do it?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you show us the UV map? Perhaps also show what you have tried/what isn't working.  It's hard to answer questions like this without some kind of reference images.